# Apache 2.4 How to restrict a site to a single IP address

Tags: apache, configuration, apache2

For Apache 2.2 it was

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.4.5/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride all
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Directory>
```

But I cant find how to do this for Apache 2.4? The above directives are not compatible

Comment: This would be better posted to serverfault.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for mod_authz_host has changed with version 2.4.

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.4.5/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
    Require local
</Directory>
```

Look in the docs for more details.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_authz_host.html